# Kivy: I am trying to bind a button into the Popup but keep getting the error __init__ takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to bind the "Removed" Button into the Popup in Kivy app using Python. However, I keep getting the error:

"box.add_widget(Button("Removed", on_press=pop.dismiss))
TypeError: **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"

The below is a snippet of my code.

Python Code

```
class MyMainApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data_tables = None
        self.slider = None
        self.date_selected = None
        self.txt = "0"

    def build(self):
        self.kv = Builder.load_file("main1.kv")
        return self.kv

    ######## Screen 3 ######

    def add_datatable(self):
        count = 1
        condition = "Bad"   # MACHINE LEARNING: LOAD IN TOOL'S CONDITION HERE!!
        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}, 
                        size_hint=(0.545, 0.57), 
                        check = True, 
                        rows_num = 5, 
                        use_pagination = True,
                        pagination_menu_height = "240dp",
                        column_data=[
                            ("No.", dp(25)),
                            ("Tools",dp(28)),
                            ("Slot Number", dp(26)),
                            ("Condition", dp(26))
                        ],
                        row_data=[
                            (count, "Kuglen", "1", condition),
                            ("", "", "", "")
                        ]
                        )

        if condition == "Bad":
            print("Bad tool")
            tool_img = "Capture.png"   
            box = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", padding=(10))
            pop = Popup(title="Faulty tool detected", auto_dismiss=True, content=Image(source=tool_img),
                size_hint=(None,None), size=(450,520))
            box.add_widget(Button("Removed", on_press=pop.dismiss))  ##The part with error
            pop.open()


        self.data_tables.bind(on_check_press=self.check_press) #Create a function check_press
        self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.row_press)                    
        self.root.ids.data_scr.ids.data_layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)

    def change_screen(self, screen: str):
        self.root.current = screen

    def check_press(self, instance_table, current_row): current_row: has the values of rows that have been pressed
        print(instance_table, current_row)

    def row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row): 
        print(instance_table, instance_row)
```

Comment: If "Removed" is supposed to be the button text, then you need to pass that as `text="Button"`.

Comment: Oh right..this is part of the error. However, after adding "text" in, I am still unable to bind the "Removed" button with the Popup screen.